# Live video Streaming Conversion

Tags: java, video-streaming, ip-camera

I am able to show the live streaming from my ip camera through jframe and applet , I need to convert this mpg stream to mp4 format so that i can show this in html5 video tag ..Can anybody suggest how to do that and video should be still live without any time lag ....One more thing to view streaming I am hitting the public ip of camera and this is how I am capturing video, is there any effect on the efficiency if large number of people are watching the video at the same time ..
Please suggest ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, know that you can't do live streaming with regular MP4 video format. "Progressive download" MP4 files have an index at the beginning of the file, this cannot be written before you finished encoding the entire movie. There is a variant of MP4 which indexes every small chunk of video separately, but it is not widely supported by HTML5 browsers.

I can suggest several options:

1. Use FLASH rather than HTML5 and convert the video to FLV. However, I'm not aware of a Java tool to do this conversion.
2. Use HTTP live streaming and set up a dedicated streaming server to do the transcoding. There is plenty of server software that can do that, such as Wowza server, Adobe FMS, and even Microsoft's Expression Encoder+IIS. You can also find SaaS solutions for that and EC2 images of such servers.